# Renaming a user in AD, (Contact name, Login ID and Email address)

Tags: active-directory, exchange-2007

We have a user who recently got married and her name has changed. I'm capable of renaming the user, login ID and Email address, one by one, but is there a proper way to go about doing this?

Is there anything special i would need to be aware of if I renamed the USER id and or the Email address? Is it going to disconnect or something?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't really anything special about this.  Make the changes you need to in ADUC and then use the Exchange Management Console to modify the user's mailbox properties.  You should change the default e-mail address on the exchange server to reflect the new e-mail address (it will be **highlighted in bold)**, but keep the old e-mail address listed on the "E-Mail Addresses" tab as well so that they continue to receive e-mail from individuals that haven't updated the sending address.

Comment: Make note that user profile folders and/or redirected folders won't be renamed from the original user name. They'll continue to work but this can cause confusion down the road, especially when new IT staff come on board who aren't aware of the previous name.

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using Win 2k3, you should just click the user in AD Users and computers, press F2, rename, and it will automatically show a windows with the properties you mention (to change them as you need to).
And no, it shouldn't disconnect anything (I think you mean an Exchange Mailbox).

Comment: Yes, I was refering to an exchange disconnect, and were on 2K8, but I think this will help. Thanks !